What happens if a ball collides with a wall that provides a perfect rebound and the wall disappears after half the contact time?
I would like to pose a question that currently sparks my curiosity, and I would appreciate your help in answering it.
Imagine a ball colliding with a wall that provides a perfect rebound for the ball. This means that at the moment of impact, the wall exerts a force on the ball during a contact time of $Δt$, resulting in an acceleration of $2v$, where $v$ is the speed of the ball upon impact with the wall. Under these same conditions, what do you think would happen if the wall suddenly disappeared after only half the contact time, i.e., after a time of $Δt/2$? Would the ball stop or continue its motion?

One assumes a wall that provides 'a perfect rebound' is one that does not flex and absorb energy, but also does not move (so does not obey conservation of momentum).

A simple but appropriate model of this is that the wall is rigid and the ball suffers an elastic compression during the collision. At the half-way point the ball is compressed and its center of mass has zero velocity. So if the wall now vanishes the center of mass of the ball does not move afterwards: the ball is stopped. However it is compressed, and now it will expand again and oscillate a bit. During this subsequent motion the outer surface of the ball may be, briefly, in an oscillatory motion, without causing any net displacement of the center of mass.
P.S. a lesson of this is: when you want to consider changes to some otherwise standard scenario, consider making your model more realistic in the first instance, so that it can be interpreted easily in the new scenario.

I think the question is tricky, because at first sight, a careless reader could say that the force is impulsive, i.e.,
$$
F = -2mv \delta (t-t_0)
$$
Where $t_0$ is the exact moment of impact, and the interval $\Delta t$ is null. Since $0/2 =0$, for delta-like force nothing changes and the ball rebounds. If we want to consider finite time intervals (with non null measure), we need to consider something more smooth than a dirac delta for a force. We could search in this MSE question for suggestions and possibilities, or look at this wiki article about nascent delta functions. Now, the answer would depend which kind of function we choose to express this force.
If we choose the hat function (see it in second link),
$$
F(t) = \frac{-2mv}{\Delta t}
\begin{cases}
0, \quad t \leq -\Delta t/2\\
1 + {t\over \Delta t}, \quad -\Delta t/2 < t \leq 0\\
1 - {t\over \Delta t}, \quad 0 < t \leq \Delta t/2 \\
0, \quad t > \Delta t/2.
\end{cases}
$$
The wall disappear in $t=0$, so we integrate it in the interval $[-\Delta t/2,0]$, which gives
$$
\Delta p = \int_{-\Delta t/2}^0 F(t) dt = -mv.
$$
So it transfer half the momentum that it would in the whole interval, which implies
$$
P_{f} = P_i + \Delta p = 0
$$
i.e., the ball stops. It was expected, since the hat function distribute the force equally in the interval. I would say that any function symmetric w.r.t. the $t=0$ would give the same result, because the momentum transfered by the ball is the area under the curve.
Since a asymmetric force would break the time-reversal symmetry, than the previous result would be true by any force we choose, the previous result would be general in any case we have such symmetry. So the ball stops.

Time-reversal symmetry could be break if we have dissipative forces acting in the system. But since we are neglecting the air friction and inelastic deformation of the ball, I would consider that this symmetry is not break.
If we consider the possibility of an assymetric force, It would make sense to consider that it transfer more momentum in the first half time interval, since for real balls, this force is due to elastic restoring force, which starts bigger, and gets wicker as the ball suffers plastic deformation. It would imply a rebound.
